cmake add_custom_command always runs
I have some auto code generation process that I want to integrate to my build process. I added a custom command and target to cmake to generate the code. Something like this:
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/auto/generated.h
    COMMAND bash -c "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/generate_code --output ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/auto/generated.h input_file.c"
    DEPENDS input_file.c
)

add_custom_target(generate_target
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/auto/generated.h
)

Then I have my main target depend on generate_target.
The problem is that the custom command always runs, even if there was no change in input_file.c. What am I doing wrong?

Are you sure that the modification timestamp of input_file.c does not change? Why are you running bash?

Check that your command actually modifies the file you mention in OUTPUT clause?
